# How to debug into native code when debugging a unit test in Visual Studio?

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-2012

With 'enable native code debugging' set on the unit test project's Debug settings tab, I am unable to step into native code when debugging unit tests.

Looking at the Modules window, it's clear that only managed code is being debugged - there are no native DLLs listed.

Is there a way to debug native code in Visual Studio unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2013, and using googletest with the [GoogleTestRunner extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9dd47c21-97a6-4369-b326-c562678066f0):  I couldn't properly debug via the Test Explorer's "Debug this test" menu.  I had to debug into the unit test project's executable itself (right click on unit test project, hit Debug).

By "not properly debug" I mean:  I was able to stop at a breakpoint, and see a data value by hovering over a variable in the code window - but I didn't get any typical debugger windows (call stack, autos, locals, modules, etc.) *nor were there any such windows available under the Debug/Windows menu item*!

Not sure if this is your problem, since you didn't specify whether you're using Visual Studio's built-in native C++ unit tests or not.  But I believe it might be an issue with running tests inside the Test Explorer.